# Is there a non Java alternative to OSGi?

Tags: java, c++, osgi

Is there an OSGi like framework that is based on C/C++?
I have plenty of legacy code in C/C++ that would be too expensive to be ported to Java.

Comment: One option is to use OSGi in Java *and* use your C/C++ code -- e.g., through through SWIG, JNA or JNI.

Comment: OSGi frameworks support JNI libraries including updating them by unloading and reloading as required.

Comment: Even though it is easy to use JNI and native libs with OSGi, it has a huge drawback. If, for whatever reason, the native code crashes, the entire VM also crashes. This might be a reason for not using JNI. A solution using something like Apache Celix with remote services might be more useful in such case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a list of OSGi-like C/C++ frameworks I know of (and which are still active):

- [Apache Celix](http://incubator.apache.org/celix/) [Language: C, License: Apache License 2.0]
- [SOF](http://sof.tiddlyspot.com/) [Language: C++, License: Unknown]
- [CTK](http://www.commontk.org/index.php/Documentation/Plugin_Framework) [Language: C++, License: Apache License 2.0]
- [nOSGi](http://www-vs.informatik.uni-ulm.de/proj/nosgi/) [Language: C++, License: GPLv3]
- [Poco OSP](http://www.appinf.com/en/products/osp.html) [Language: C++, License: Commercial]
- [CppMicroServices](http://cppmicroservices.org/) [Language: C++, License: Apache License 2.0]

This [blog post](http://blog.cppmicroservices.org/2012/03/29/osgi-and-c++/) gives a high-level overview about these frameworks.

Comment: I'd have expected nOSGI to be based on .NET…

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Apache Celix](http://incubator.apache.org/celix/), which gives you an OSGi-like module framework for C, combined with C/Java interoperability through OSGi's Remote Services mechanism.

Comment: One of the things we (Apache Celix) are currently investigating is, is how to extend Celix so that it is also possible to use C++ in a natural way. Currently Celix only focusses on C.

Answer (score 1):

Since OSGi is nowadays a complete ecosystem with many standards, substandards and so on - the strict answer is: No, because it relies on to many things specific to Java (bytecode, classloading, garbage collection, ...) which are not part of C/C++ and which cannot be even simulated - especially for legacy code.

But if you tell us what parts of OSGi you are interested in and especially what parts you consider not relevant for your code, answers may come up.

Meanwhile you can browse some other similar questions on this site or use the search:

- [C++ modularization framework (like OSGi) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627114/c-modularization-framework-like-osgi)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588954/c-plug-in-framework
- [Portable C++ Component Design](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5127981/947357)

Comment: Another similar question, with answers, can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069144/how-to-compose-osgi-based-project-with-c-based-project